# agent based programming using native programming language

Tags: multithreading, native, user-agent, agents-jade, agent-based-modeling

so basically I am interested in building an agent-based simulation of a battleground.

There are a lot of frameworks for agent-based models such as JADE, etc.. but due to certain constraint, I can only implement it using only native programming language for example C++ or Java without any frameworks or libraries.

I've searched in google but I can't seem to find any good tutorials on agent-oriented programming.

Where should I start? or are there any tutorials for a complete beginner in agent-based programming?

THX b4

Answer (score 1):

Look at this frameworks:
[Relacy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/relacy/?source=navbar),
[SObjectizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sobjectizer/?source=directory)

Answer (score 0):

Beginners should probably start with the template models.
Here is a tutorial using Python:
http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/14/2/5.html 
Here is a tutorial using Repast:
http://code.google.com/p/repast-demos/wiki/StupidModel

hth.